# Validate that password doesn't contain 3+ consecutive characters from name

Tags: java, regex, validation, passwords

I need to do this following password validation in Java

- Must be at least 8 characters in length
- Must contain at least 1 number
- Must contain at least 1 upper case letter
- Must contain at least 1 lower case letter
- Cannot contain 3 or more consecutive characters from your full name or your username (e.g. If your name is `Will` you couldn't have the password `Stiller458`)

I have the first 4 points, how do I do the last one?

Currently I have:

```
String pattern = "^(?=.*[^a-zA-Z])(?=.*[a-z])(?=.*[A-Z])\\S{8,}$";
boolean passwordValidation = originalPassword.matches(pattern);
```

Comment: Do you have to do this with a regex? That last point is probably not possible.

Comment: Who told you to do that in regex? You should steal him a donnut!

Comment: Thank guys, I've been fighting with people for not doing it using RegEx, they insist its possible and when I told them to give me the RegEx they have just walked off.

Comment: For one number, `[^a-zA-Z]` should be `[0-9]`. And you probably want `.` instead of `\\S`.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

For your 1,2,3,4 case

```
^(?=.*\d)(?=.*[a-z])(?=.*[A-Z])[a-zA-Z\d]{8,}$
```

For your 5th case

```
public boolean isValid(final String userName,final String password)
{
    for(int i=0;(i+2)<userName.length();i++)
          if(password.indexof(userName.substring(i,i+2))!=-1)
                return false;
    return true;
}
```

Comment: I am getting an "java.lang.StringIndexOutOfBoundsException: String index out of range: 8", any idea why?

Comment: @Vivek oops..check out the edit now..instead of using `userName.length()` i used `password.length()`..small error

Comment: Tnx, also I changed  if(password.indexof(userName.substring(i,i+2))!=-1) to  if(password.indexOf(userName.substring(i,i+3))!=-1) to cater to contains 3 or more

Comment: @Vivek checking for 3 is as good as checking for 4,5,6,7,.... so you only need to check for 3 characters..

Answer (score 2):

The last point is not something you do with regex. Loop through the name and check against the password instead.

Regex is good at patterns, not parsing. One way or another you have to use a loop to go through the name.