# Password Validation regex android

Tags: java, android, regex, string

I need to have following password validations :

1. At least Min Characters 8 and Maximum Characters 15
2. At least One Number and 1 special characters from (! @#$%^&*-*=+?.*);
3. At least One lower case letter
4. Password shouldn't be sub strings of username and email (min length 3 and max length 15).
5. Password should be case sensitive.

I have also looked these [answers](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16797636/validate-that-password-doesnt-contain-3-consecutive-characters-from-name) but I am confuse , should I use Input filters to achieve this or Regex?

Any help will be appreciable. It will be great if you guyz provide a working solution.

Comment: You looked at that answer and did you try it?

Comment: Yes I tried but it isn't fulfilling my complete requirement. @WiktorStribiżew could you please help me with it.

Comment: Sorry, I have no idea how you can check Req. 4 with a regex.

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew any help for rest points expect 4

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
public class Validation {

    public static void main(String[] args) {  
       String pass = "1AB%CDef555";
       String username = "manna";
       String email = "mannx@rtt.com";
       System.out.println(validiate2(pass, username,email));
    }
    // if you don't care why it fails and only want to know if valid or not 
    public static boolean validiate (String pass, String username, String email){
        String pattern = "^(?=.*[0-9])(?=.*[a-z])(?=.*[!@#$%^&*+=?-]).{8,15}$";
        if(pass.matches(pattern)){
            for(int i=0;(i+3)<username.length();i++){
                if(pass.contains(username.substring(i,i+3)) || username.length()<3 || username.length()>15){
                   return false; 
                }                  
            }
            for(int i=0;(i+3)<email.length();i++){
                if(pass.contains(email.substring(i,i+3)) || email.length()<3 || email.length()>15){
                   return false; 
                }                  
            }
            return true;
        }
        return false;    
    }
    // if you want to know which requirement was not met
    public static boolean validiate2 (String pass, String username, String email){
        if (pass.length() < 8 || pass.length() >15 ){
            System.out.println("pass too short or too long");
            return false;
        }
        if (username.length() < 3 || username.length() >15 ){
            System.out.println("username too short or too long");
            return false;
        }
        if (!pass.matches(".*\\d.*")){
            System.out.println("no digits found");
            return false;
        } 

        if (!pass.matches(".*[a-z].*")) {
            System.out.println("no lowercase letters found");
            return false; 
        }
        if (!pass.matches(".*[!@#$%^&*+=?-].*")) {
            System.out.println("no special chars found");
            return false; 
        } 
        if (containsPartOf(pass,username)) {
            System.out.println("pass contains substring of username");
            return false; 
        }
        if (containsPartOf(pass,email)) {
            System.out.println("pass contains substring of email");
            return false; 
        }
        return true;           
    }

    private static boolean containsPartOf(String pass, String username) {
        int requiredMin = 3
        for(int i=0;(i+requiredMin)<username.length();i++){
            if(pass.contains(username.substring(i,i+requiredMin))){
               return true; 
            }                  
        }
        return false;        
    }    
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can try this one:

```
^(?!.*(user|emailaddress))(?=.*\d)(?=.*[! @#$%^&*=+?.-])(?=.*[a-z]).{8,15}$
```

Make sure you replace the user and emailaddress by your variable

[Explanation](https://regex101.com/r/pN5mWQ/1)

This code works fine for me:

```
public class NewClass1 {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        NewClass1 nc = new NewClass1();
        nc.check("abcd123-", "userName", "abc@yahoo.com");
        nc.check("userName1-", "userName", "abc@y.c");
        nc.check("abc@y.c1b", "userName", "abc@y.c");
        nc.check("abcy.c1b", "userName", "abc@y.c");
        nc.check("abcd123-", "userName", "abc@yahoo.com");
    }

    public void check(String string, String userName, String email) {

        final String regex = "^(?!.*(" + userName + "|" + email + "))(?=.*\\d)(?=.*[! @#$%^&*=+?.-])(?=.*[a-z]).{8,15}$";
        final Pattern pattern = Pattern.compile(regex, Pattern.MULTILINE);
        final Matcher matcher = pattern.matcher(string);
        if (matcher.find()) {
            System.out.println(string + "Full match: " + matcher.group(0));
        } else {
            System.out.println("no match");
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: @Maverick_Mrt Even replacing user|emailaddress with my values, it still  doesn't completing 4th point.

Comment: @rahulsharma https://regex101.com/r/pN5mWQ/3 look here .. if the user name is 'user' or the email address is 'email' it doesn't match ... just tell me by editing in the link if it is working or not ... then i will look into your code

Comment: @rahulsharma please have a look in my updated answer. having code snippet... let me know if it works for you

Comment: Dear @maverick_Mrt there's shouldn't be substring min 3 or max 15 character , your answer works only when "user" or "email" is entered , it fails if inputs "use@1234" , see https://regex101.com/r/pN5mWQ/3

Comment: in your original question you wrote, At least Min Characters 8 and Maximum Characters 15 ... moreover, use my code and append the following line ... nc.check("use@1234-", "userName", "use@1234"); it will say no match... it should say no match isn't it ?

Answer (score 0):

There is [great library](https://github.com/ragunathjawahar/android-saripaar) for that.
It's uses anotations for field and has rich customatization.
I think that #4 still needs to be done by hand but you should definitly check out the library.

Here's the example from github:

```
@Password(min = 6, scheme = Password.Scheme.ALPHA_NUMERIC_MIXED_CASE_SYMBOLS)
private EditText passwordEditText;
```

Cheers.

Comment: Thanks @makvasic , but I'm actually not looking for a lib to achieve this